# How to display images accourding to choise from dropdown?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm creating a Django website where I want to implement such functionality.

There will be one `Dropdown list` and one `submit button`. When user selects any item from dropdown list - An image according to user selection will be displayed.

ie. There's drop-down list containing names of animals and one submit button. When user selects any animal from list, photo/details of that animal should appear before pressing submit button.

I don't know how to create link between them. Any reference to such work or advice would be appreciate.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You likely want to use async request with JavaScript here (look for AJAX or JS Fetch API)
Attach it to `onchange` event of select element and send it's value to django.

Django will have a view that processes this request and returns a `JsonResponse` with image url.

Alternatively you can load all urls before hand and just select them on page without request, but anyway if you don't want to press button to take change - you need JavaScript.